# The existence of a specific kind of independent set in a connected graph satisfying the following property

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a connected finite graph satisfying that every edge $uv$ of $G$ belongs to a "triangle" $uvw$ such that $uv,uw\in E(G),\ vw\notin E(G)$ or $uv,vw\in E(G),\ uw\notin E(G)$(in other words, every edge of $G$ is part of a vee shape), i.e. of an induced $ K_{ 1,2}$.

For any independent set $S$ in $G$ with $|S|\geqslant2$ and $v\in S$, define
$$d_S(v)=\mid\{u\in V(G)\setminus S:N_G(u)\cap S=\{v\}\}\mid$$
and 
$$D_S=\max\{d_S(v):v\in S\},\\D(G)=\min\{D_S:\text{$S$ ranges over all independent sets in $G$ with $|S|\geqslant2$}\}.$$
My question is whether it is possible that for any given integer $n\geq1$, we can always find $G$ such that $D(G)>n$.

Comment: Not always. For G an odd cycle on more than three vertices, I believe no such independent set E exists.  Gerhard "Possibly True For Bipartite Graphs" Paseman, 2018.08.25.

Comment: just a nitpick - do not use $E$ to denote both edges of $G$ and an independent set.

Comment: you are also not following the standard in graph theory convention that a triangle is a complete subgraph on 3 vertices.

Comment: as well, I think, it is important whether $G$ is finite, or not.

Comment: Gerhard Paseman: Thanks, I have revised my question.

Comment: If uv is an edge, must it be that vw is not an edge, or can uw not be an edge?  Is it enough that every edge is part of a vee shape, or is it important that the v part have vw be a nonedge?  Gerhard "How Important Are Labels Here?" Paseman, 2018.08.27.

Comment: Gerhard Paseman: It is enough that every edge is part of a vee shape. I have revised my question.

Comment: I guess my answer to [your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309246/asking-for-an-example-of-a-graph-g-satisfying-the-following-property) answers this one too. Looks like I posted it in the wrong place. Oh well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking for an example of a graph $G$ satisfying the following property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309246/asking-for-an-example-of-a-graph-g-satisfying-the-following-property)

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $D(K_2\square K_{n+2})=D((C_{3n+2})^n)=n.$

(I posted these examples in my answer to [your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309246/asking-for-an-example-of-a-graph-g-satisfying-the-following-property) before I looked at this question.)